# How to solve SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 in Lumen?

Tags: mysql, lumen

I have this strange issue. The query in question is

```
 UPDATE TABLE1 SET VALUE2 ='value2' WHERE VALUE1 = 'value1'; 
 INSERT INTO TABLE1(VALUE1, VALUE2)  
 SELECT 'value1' AS VALUE1, 'value2' AS VALUE2
 FROM TABLE1 x
 WHERE x.VALUE1 = 'value1' 
 HAVING COUNT(*) = 0;
```

I am trying to perform update and insert with the same query. It runs fine with MySQL workbench. However from Lumen Controller it is throwing the error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: You gave a `Syntax error or access violation` , It does not seem to be a syntax, so it must be an access violation ?

Comment: @Luuk, Every other query is working except this.

Comment: Did you try to run two queries in one call? Most query APIs do not allow multi-query by default.

Comment: Bill you could be right, I overlooked that one...

Comment: *`HAVING COUNT(*) = 0;`* This condition **ALWAYS** results in empty rowset.

Comment: *it is throwing the error* - never post a part of error message, always provide complete text.

Comment: @BillKarwin, I tried to run those queries in one call by putting it in a procedure, still same result. I couldn't figure out the issue and used query builder instead.

Comment: @Akina, that was the complete error message + the query

Comment: @Akina, No, It doesn't if you don't use GROUP BY

Comment: @mapuna `HAVING COUNT(*) = 0;` means - return rows which are absent. I.e. return nothing. GROUP BY presence/absence does not effect.

Comment: @Akina, Actually the purpose of the above query is that if any row exists by `'value1' AS VALUE1` then update else insert the same. When there is no rows, `HAVING COUNT(*) = 0` returns true and it performs an INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out the issue and used laravel query builder instead